# Get API using Python - Timeout issue

Tags: java, python, api, async-await

Q) I want to call a GET API using python which is taking time to get a response back. 
I don't need to wait for the response I just want to send a request and close the thread. Please help me with this issue. What should I do in this case?

```
def call_oms(in_params, thread_ts):
    url_list = {
        "static": "http://ptw01am1ap001:2003/execute"
    }
    executionId = str(random())

    # real data
    order_id =in_params["order_id"]
    fulfillment = in_params["fulfillment"]
#    env = in_params["env"]

    # mocking data
#    order_id = "CX01-1043562345"
#    fulfillment = "shiptohome"
    env = "static"
    print("Consumming API -- In_params")
    print(order_id)
    print(fulfillment)

    url = url_list[env] + "?orderNumber=" + order_id + "&testCaseName="+fulfillment + "&executionId="+ thread_ts
    print(url) - This is printing the url with the parameters we send this to message
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: I think you should use requests.post() instead of requests.get()

Comment: It is actually a GET API, I cannot do requests.post()

Answer (score 0):

May `requests.get(url, timeout=0)` help you?

Addition:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from random import random

def call_oms(in_params, thread_ts):
    async def get(url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                await response.read()
    url_list = {
        "static": "http://ptw01am1ap001:2003/execute"
    }
    executionId = str(random())

    # real data
    order_id =in_params["order_id"]
    fulfillment = in_params["fulfillment"]
    # env = in_params["env"]

    # mocking data
    # order_id = "CX01-1043562345"
    # fulfillment = "shiptohome"
    env = "static"
    print("Consumming API -- In_params")
    print(order_id)
    print(fulfillment)

    url = url_list[env] + "?orderNumber=" + order_id + "&testCaseName="+fulfillment + "&executionId="+ thread_ts
    print(url)
    courutine=get(url)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(courutine))
```